# Can I use MERGE INTO in Apache Derby version 10.11?

Tags: java, derby

I Am facing issue while using MERGE with prepare statement for derby. Always giving me error for MERGE in SQL. MY derby version is 10.10 is there ant alternative (I am using MERGE INTO for Insert and Update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Derby documentation says:

> The MERGE statement is valid only after a database has been fully
>   upgraded to Derby Release 10.11 or higher. (See "Upgrading a database"
>   in the Derby Developer's Guide for more information.) This statement
>   has no meaning in a database that is at Release 10.10 or lower.